# FakeBold in fontspec lualatex, method used?

Tags: luatex, fontspec

If I were a modestly decent programmer, I would look into the code for this. But not being such...

Without knowing the algorithms, I am confident that `fontspec` FakeStretch and FakeSlant are unlikely to introduce vector drawing errors in the glyph outlines. These can be done by relatively simple linear transforms.

But I am not confident about FakeBold. For example, the FontForge font editor has menus for emboldening glyphs. Its algorithm has problems, and can introduce vector drawing errors (or unexpected changes) in some glyphs, even when using only PostScript outlines in an OpenType font. This, I know from experience. My workflow dislikes vector errors, and I usually must resort to inspecting fonts (via FontForge) before using them.

So, my question: What does `fontspec` do for FakeBold? If it makes copies of a glyph, and overlaps the copies with slight offsets, that would be a problem in my workflow (might not be a problem for others). If it moves glyph control points away from the filled centerlines, without adding new control points, and then removes any generated overlaps, then that is likely to be good. There are other possibilities.

I note that the availability of these features depends on compiler, and on recency of versions. I use only `lualatex`.

EDIT: The comments suffice. I can take it from there. No further answer needed, but I will leave the question posted, in case anyone else is interested.

EDIT2: As I mentioned above, it seems that the (current) method used by FontForge, to embolden characters, has some problems. Based on the comments, I tried this in FontForge: Copy a potentially-difficult character to background. Stroke the foreground by some reasonable amount. Merge the background into the foreground. Eliminate overlap. A few tests show all good. Although this is not identical to what `fontspec` does, it is very similar. I conclude that the risk of FakeBold is probably low. I have not had the opportunity to check this via the most stringent PDF/X standards, but I expect that it will pass. However, I do not use glyph shaping (such as for Arabic) so I do not know what happens there.

Comment: I must admit I never checked but I thought it stroked the outline path as well as the fill so it fudges the thing to be wider.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Stroking the paths (clockwise and anticlockwise) would certainly be one way to do it. Probably safe in most cases. But it would still be necessary to ensure that no overlaps were created.

Comment: as @DavidCarlisle says it sets the line width and then changes the text rendering mode to 2 (fill + stroke). The rest is up to the pdf viewer and the font itself.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That makes sense. Not sure how it will affect my workflow. Only way to check, is to create some documents with possibly hazardous glyphs, and see what happens. By "see what happens" I mean hearing complaints from someone else.

Comment: @rallg it would be great if you could share the results of your experiment once you try it.

Comment: @Niranjan See my EDIT2.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The method for FakeBold appears to be OK,after some testing.

Comment: @rallg thanks for this